# Get the last item for each users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get the last `Programme` for each `User` when displaying a table of users. (`User` has one `Profile` and `Profile` belongs to `User`)

In my controller, I am getting all programmes, like so:

`@programmes = Programme.all`

```
<table>
 <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <% @programmes.each do |programme| %>
      <% if programme.client == profile.user.id %>
       <%= programme.description %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

But how do I get **the last** programme for each user?

Thanks!

Comment: What does mean last programme ? Can you give the criteria for last programme regarding the user ? What's the link between User and Programme ?

Comment: It's just a one to many relationship, I just want the last one created, but within a loop, where I cant use each user.id to do my request when loading the page, or can I, and that's what I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Given your setup, here's how you could display the *last* programme for each user:

```
<table>
  <% @profiles.each do |profile|
    <% user = profile.user
    <% last_programme = user.programmes.last %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= last_programme.try(:description) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last

Comment: If a `user` doesn't have a `programme`, calling `description` on `last_prgramme` will raise an error —you can prevent this by using the `try` method to retrieve the `description`.

Comment: If you only want to display users who *have* a `programme`, you should modify your controller to only assign profiles for users who have programmes to your `@profiles` variable.  Then you can eliminate using the `try`.

Answer (score 1):

To find the last record you could just call `.last`

You could also call `.first` `.second` `.third`

[ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last)

```
Person.last # returns the last object fetched by SELECT * FROM people
Person.where(["user_name = ?", user_name]).last
Person.order("created_on DESC").offset(5).last
Person.last(3) # returns the last three objects fetched by SELECT * FROM people.
```

In your case `<% user.programmes.last %>` will do the trick